# Git merge branches symbolically

Tags: git, git-merge

I have two branches A and B and I want to merge B into A. However, I don't want any changes from B to transfer to A. A should remain unchanged except for manual changes done after the merge. I know that this technically goes against the whole idea of merging, but this is about *documenting* that these branches are related. What I do want, is that the graph of the repository shows a merge between these two graphs at the corresponding commit i.e. I want git to "think" that there was an actual merge.

One possible approach would be to do a `reset` after the merge. However, this does not in a graph as described above. There is no actual link between the branches.

Comment: What's the motivation behind this "documentation" if the branches aren't really merged? You can add a commit comment, but that wouldn't do anything substantial.

Comment: @Kraylog For example one could merge only a single file manually (i.e. line by line) which otherwise would not work because of the actual state of the branches.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is called "null merge". Use [`--strategy=ours`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt--sltstrategygt):

```
git checkout A
git merge -s ours B
```

PS. Don't confuse `--strategy=ours` and 
`--strategy-option=ours`; the latter is an option for default recursive strategy; the option merges files that don't have conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

If you take the `diff` of Branch B->A, and the `diff` of A->B, you can merge B->A, then commit the `diff` A->B, essentially undoing any changes.  You will have an extra commit and the changes will be tracked though.